# How do I get pin messages in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to get the latest pinned message in the current channel but I don't know how to get the pinned message. If you guys know how to get the latest pinned message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to retrieve all the pins of a channel using `channel.pins()`, as seen in the code below. This will give you a `list` of messages, assuming the channel has pins.

```py
pins = await ctx.channel.pins() # a list of all the channel's pins
await ctx.send(pins[0]) # sends all the information in the channel's first pin
await ctx.send(pins[0].content) # sends the content of the message. 
                                # An error will occur if there is no message content
```

[image: Possible use in a cmd]

**Docs**:

- [`await pins()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=pins#discord.abc.Messageable.pins)
- [`discord.Message` attributes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=pins#discord.Message)